# Storing derived object into container of base type

Tags: c++

I have some fundamental problems to understand the behavior of storing derived objects into container of base type in C++.

Can anyone explain the output of the below code? I thought the behavior should be the same in both functions.

```
// Output
test_func1
UseCount: 1
UseCount: 2
test_func2
UseCount: 1
UseCount: 1   // Why???
```

```c
class base_class
{
public:
    base_class() { }
    virtual ~base_class() { }
};

class derived_class : public base_class
{
public:
    derived_class(const std::shared_ptr<int>& i)
        : base_class(),
          i_(i)
    { }

    ~derived_class() { }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<int> i_;
};

void test_func1()
{
    std::cout << "test_func1" << std::endl;
    std::vector<derived_class> v;
    std::shared_ptr<int> i(new int(100));
    std::cout << "UseCount: " << i.use_count() << std::endl;
    v.push_back(derived_class(i));
    std::cout << "UseCount: " << i.use_count() << std::endl;
}

void test_func2()
{
    std::cout << "test_func2" << std::endl;
    std::vector<base_class> v;
    std::shared_ptr<int> i(new int(100));
    std::cout << "UseCount: " << i.use_count() << std::endl;
    v.push_back(derived_class(i));
    std::cout << "UseCount: " << i.use_count() << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    test_func1();
    test_func2();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read up on [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

Comment: Thanks. This is my first time to hear this term...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in the second case your base class was copy-constructed from the derived class passed to `push_back` method. And your base class does not store `shared_ptr<int>`. You derived class instance was destroyed after `push_back` returned.

```
void test_func2()
{
    std::cout << "test_func2" << std::endl;
    std::vector<base_class> v;
    std::shared_ptr<int> i(new int(100)); //use count is 1
    std::cout << "UseCount: " << i.use_count() << std::endl;
    v.push_back(derived_class(i)); //base_class is copy constructed here and store in v
    //derived_class() is destroyed ans use count is still 1
    std::cout << "UseCount: " << i.use_count() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You **can not** store derived objects in std::vector of base class. Try to remember that.

That vector stores the base class, nothing else. On push_back the derived parts are sliced off.

If you want have a polymorphic collection, look up how to do that, 'polymorphic STL collection' is good query either on SO or in general.